# Building a mobile app with Html5

Tags: html, cordova, mobile-application

We have to build an app which should run on iOS and android. For expenses reason we decided to to it with html5 and phonegap.

Now we have to decide which mobile framework we wann use for it. I know there are already a lot of this issues and I also already did a lot of research. But I'm still not sure which one we should pick.

I've heard a lot down side points from Jquery mobile, but on the other hands it seems there is nothing really better, beside senche touch, out there.

What are your experience, what whould you suggest?

I'm looking forward hearing your opinion
(let me now if you need further information for evaluating)

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend . 
http://css.dzone.com/articles/sencha-touch-v-jquery-mobile 
I dont use either as I prefer my own custom interface.

Answer (score 1):

Building PhoneGap with Bootstrap and AngularJS is a breeze.

AngularJS provide a really nice separation between Route, Model, View, and Controller.  Learn Angular directives and stop writing spaghetti js dom interaction code.

Bootstrap, though not as nice as jQM for mobile features (maybe until v3), still provide a nice starter CSS such as (navbar, fixed top, bottom, etc...)  And if you know your css, then  I think Bootstrap is more flexible than jQM.  Combine with some nodejs build script to compile your less file to css and you are all set.  Glyphicons is also a good starter set of asset/images.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you would have done a lot of research on this but from my experience I would suggest you to take a look at Sencha Touch + Phonegap combination.

The reason why I opted for Sencha Touch over Jquery Mobile is that the JM is quite sluggish when it comes to page transition and animation. Whereas, Sencha Touch provides you all-in-one place regarding building a rich mobile app with HTML5, CSS and Javascript. The only thing about ST is that you might require to learn some Ext JS which is used by Sencha Touch to create components. They do have a lot of documentations which you can refer to.

You can refer these links to kickstart on Sencha:

https://github.com/senchalearn

http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch/

All the best! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I think the choice is between Sencha touch and JQM.

The thing is we are familiar with the backbone framework, so at this point we are prefering jqm. But I read a lot more good things about Sencha Touch. So I think its worth it to make the effort to learn the Ext Js.

Have you experience with sencha touch and phonegapp? Does this work well?

Comment: Yes, it really does. I am working an app which uses ST combined with Phonegap. Infact, I use Phonegap as a wrapper and to implement AdMob, access some native features. It seems to be a great option and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

We have just started working with PhoneGap in my studio and we are using Backbone.js + Handlebars.js and Bootstrap or Ratchet depending on the case. It seems to work very well.

If you want some more resources on that I will suggest you start with 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/05/top-10-performance-techniques-for-phonegap-applications/

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/05/architecting-a-phonegap-application-video-slides/

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/sample-mobile-phonegap-application-with-backbone-js-and-ratchet/

Really good resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Never heard of ratchet. I will have a look. I know Bootstrap though. 
But I'll miss there then some nice features.